# Images are not showing in pdf created using velocity template

Tags: java, image, pdf, velocity

I create pdf using Velocity template, but i am not able to put images in pdf.
I am adding url into context object and accessing that object into eot.vm file, url is going proper but still images are not displaying in pdf.

Thanks & Regards,
Tushar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that URL you are passing is sending `IMAGE` as response not an full html page.
i was passing URL that was sending me a whole html page, so i was unable to see images.
But now its fixed.

Please visit below link:

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/2907/how-to-access-image-generated-via-velocity-template-confluence